# AWS Opensearch termvectors doesn't count term_statistics for all documents

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I uploaded several text documents to it, and when perform

```
GET <my-index>/_termvectors/<docId>?fields=content
{
 "field_statistics": false,
 "term_statistics": true,
 "positions": false,
 "payloads": false,
 "offsets": false
}
```

only that document is considered, not the others. Meaning that `doc_freq` is always `1`, and `ttf` is the same as `term_freq`, for all the terms.
Of course there are lot of terms present in multiple documents, and locally on Elasticsearch it works as expected.
Is this some problem or constraint on AWS Opensearch, and can that be configured to work as per documentation?

Comment: I assumed that when searching by a specific DocId, then it is only that document that will be considered?

Could you show what you mean that it works on ES? Perhaps full query/response?

Comment: Please check [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/docs-termvectors.html#docs-termvectors-api-term-stats) about `term_statistics` option.
On local ES, with the same set of documents, these values are correct. E.g. If term occurs in two documents, its `doc_freq` is 2.